# Spark Persist Method is not getting invoked

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, persistence, cloudera

I am failing to understand the persist(StorageLevel.Memory_and_disk) working principle.
I had below code snippet which was working fine.

```
val df1= Spark.read.from.hive.table()
            // Perform a high complex calculation & Aggregation.
            .toDF()
df1.write.toAnotherHiveTable.
```

This was taking around 1hr for 140gb of data.
Stage/Task had

> 1.CalcStage = 750tasks(taking 50-55mins)
>    2.inserting to Hive Stage = 100 tasks(3-4 mins)

I had new requirement to modify the same as below.

```
val df1= Spark.read.from.hive.table()
            // Perform a high complex calculation & Aggregation.
            .toDF()


val df2=df1.filter($"exchange" === "commodities")

val finalDF = df1.join(df2)
finalDF .write.toAnotherHiveTable.
```

This started taking around 1hr 40 mins for same amount of data.
And Stage/Task had

> 1.CalcStage = 750tasks(taking 1hr 30 mins)
>   2.CalcStage = 750tasks(taking 1 hr 30 mins) // First 2 stages started running parellel. Both stage logs 
>                                                   had read from Hive table entries
>    3.inserting to Hive Stage = 100 tasks(8-10 mins)

I assumed since df1 & df2 are relied on df1 calc logic, it does calc & aggregation. And I added persist of df1 as below.

```
val df1= Spark.read.from.hive.table()
            // Perform a high complex calculation & Aggregation.
            .toDF().persist(StorageLevel.Memory_and_disk)


val df2=df1.filter($"exchange" === "commodities")

val finalDF = df1.join(df2)
finalDF .write.toAnotherHiveTable
```

I thought adding persist will help me reduce the second df from running complete calc/Aggregation. But I was wrong. DAG plan & stage logs were same as of previous run . No change was observed.

Am I missing something here.? Please help me understand why persist method did not change anything.

Comment: Can u clarify your "  // Perform a high complex calculation & Aggregation. "?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an action n then persist  your first data frame , only then the compute would be saved in ur memory